# How do I calculate percentage difference in JS?

Tags: javascript, variables, percentage, equation, rate

I'd like to calculate percentage differences between two values.

The thing I'm struggling with is the variables, I don't understand how to make it work, I don't even know how to get started.. so I'm sorry if there's a lot wrong with my code.

I want the user to be able to compare the birth rates and/or death rates between two countries. There should be a first option, where the user selects if he wants to know the birth rate or death rate. Then an option to select the first country to compare, and a third option where the user selects the second country.
But I really don't know how to actually do this. So far I got this:

```
var choice = {
birth: {
    holland: 11,
    brasil: 17,
    irannie, 19,
    //amount of people who are born every 1000 citizens
},
death: {
    holland: 8,
    brasil: 6,
    irannie: 6,

    //amount of people who die every 1000 citizens, note two values are the same.. so what should the result show? I don't understand


}




  document.getElementById('calculate').addEventListener('click', function () {
    var first= +document.getElementById('onecountry').value;
    var second= +document.getElementById('secondcountry').value;
    // var snelheid = +document.getElementById('vervoer').value;





var percentage = first / second * 100;
var resultaat=Math.round(percentage*10)/10
```

Another problem I'm facing here is that I don't know how to make the result appear based on the first option, so if the user chose birth rate it should show the first birth rate as a percentage of the second birth rate, and the same for death rate.

```
document.getElementById('div2').innerHTML = "Het verschil van het geboortecijfer ten opzichte met het andere land is  <b>" + resultaat + "</b>;
```

This is in the HTML:

```
<select id="choice">
    <option value="birth">Birth rate </option>
    <option value="death">Death rate</option>
</select>


<select id="onecountry">
    <option value="holland">Nederland</option>
    <option value="brasil">Brazillie</option>
</select>
<p></p>Het tweede land dat je wil vergelijken
<select id="secondcountry">
    <option value="holland">Nederland</option>
    <option value="brasil">Brazillie</option>
    <option value="irannie">Iran</option>
</select>

<p></p>
<p></p>Het percentageverschil is
<input id="calculate" type="button" value="Bereken!" />
```

difference is  ...

Comment: I don't think you mean an [*equation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation) (that would then be *solved*)? Are you looking to generate a *filter criterion* or *condition* rather?

Comment: I really don't know I'm not English but I mean if one country's birth rate is 17 and the other is 18 what is the difference between them in %

Comment: @azaela I've made an edit (which is currently pending review) to hopefully clarify the meaning of the question. Feel free to [edit] again or rollback my edit if it's not what you meant.

Comment: @azaela: Oh, OK, that's really [*solving an equation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_solving)

Answer (score 0):

Okay i think i see what you're trying to do. Since your option values map the keys you used in birth & death, you can pass the values from the form:

```
var first = choice.birth[document.getElementById('onecountry').value];
var second = choice.death[document.getElementById('secondcountry').value];
```

You'll want be sure that nothing comes back undefined. If you have an object like so:

```
 var myObject = {};
```

And try to access a property not set:

```
 myObject.name    // returns undefined
 myObject['name'] // returns undefined
```

it's key to check it actually exists.

```
 if (first && second) {
    var percentage = first / second * 100;
    var resultaat=Math.round(percentage*10)/10
 }
```

Hope that helps. Also in your javascript code, don't use html comments, stick with javascript ones

```
 <!-- correct use of comment -->
 <p>Hello</p>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   // correct use of a comment here
   alert("hello");
 </script>
```

Comment: Ok thanks I still don't quite understand, and one more thing, how do I show the result of the percentage if it's a death rate of a birth date.

Comment: @azaela Do you mean how do you show the birth rate as a percentage of the death rate?

Comment: @ArtOfCode No, I mean that the users first selects if he wants to know the percentage of the difference in death rate or birth rate. So for it to make sense it should only show the result of the birth date or death rate percentage.

Comment: @azaela I think I see... So you're asking how you apply this to both situations, if he selects birth rate and if he selects death rate, correct?

Comment: @ArtOfCode ehm yes I could compare it to something simple: the user selects if it wants to know the difference between the calories of two fruits, or if  it wants to know the difference between the vitamins two fruits. The user then selects which 2 fruits he will compare. The result is either de difference of the calories or the vitamins in a percentage. Hope it makes sense

Comment: Thank you so so much! That's what I wanted yeah.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve it. I've re-written the calculation method and reworked the interface. It's in English so you'll need to translate it.

The `choice` object you defined has been kept. That was good. Then, in `calculate()`, I:

- Get the statistic the user wants (birth or death rate)
- Get the first and second countries
- Get the values for each country and statistic by accessing your `choice` object (using `choice[statistic]` gets the inner `birth` or `death` object, then the extra `[firstCountry]` or `[secondCountry]` gets the country's value)
- Calculate the first country's value as a percentage of the second
- Display it.

```js
var choice = {
  birth: {
    holland: 11,
    brasil: 17,
    irannie: 19
  },
  death: {
    holland: 8,
    brasil: 6,
    irannie: 6,
  }
}

function calculate() {
  var statistic = document.getElementById("choice").value;
  var firstCountry = document.getElementById("onecountry").value;
  var secondCountry = document.getElementById("secondcountry").value;
  var firstCountryValue = choice[statistic][firstCountry];
  var secondCountryValue = choice[statistic][secondCountry];
  var percentage = Math.floor((firstCountryValue / secondCountryValue) * 100);
  document.getElementById("result").innerText = "First as a percentage of second: " + percentage;
}
```

```html
Choose statistic to compare:
<select id="choice">
  <option value="birth">Birth rate</option>
  <option value="death">Death rate</option>
</select>
<br/>Choose first country:
<select id="onecountry">
  <option value="holland">Nederland</option>
  <option value="brasil">Brazillie</option>
</select>
<br/>Choose second country:
<select id="secondcountry">
  <option value="holland">Nederland</option>
  <option value="brasil">Brazillie</option>
  <option value="irannie">Iran</option>
</select>
<br/>

<button onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
<span id="result"> 
</span>
```